# Sort and Count the array and create two property then display result on every first data

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have this sample data.

```
let data = [
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'}
];
```

I want to create a two property in this data named **countBatch** and **countGroup**.

First, I need to sort data to show them in ascending order and group each data of GroupCode, so I create this method:

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.BatchNumber === b.BatchNumber) {
        return a.GroupCode.localeCompare(b.GroupCode);
    }
    return a.BatchNumber - b.BatchNumber;
});
const sortedGroup = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
    const key = `${item.BatchNumber}-${item.GroupCode}`;
    if (!sortedGroup[key]) {
        sortedGroup[key] = [];
    }
    sortedGroup[key].push(item);
});
```

Now, I will add property in the data named **countGroup**, and then show only the counted value in the first data of array each from GroupCode, the rest should be in **null** value. For example;

```
{BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A', countGroup: 3},
{BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A', countGroup: null},
{BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A', countGroup: null},
{BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B', countGroup: 2},
{BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B', countGroup: null},
{BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'C', countGroup: 1},
{BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'A', countGroup: 1},
{BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'B', countGroup: 1},
{BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C', countGroup: 2},
{BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C', countGroup: null}
```

For the above result I create another method: I iterate over the index of `sortedGroup` so I use `Object.keys()` function and then I will make a condition that if index is equal to 0, it add value on the property(*countGroup*). Else, make the value to **null**.
Here's the method I created:

```
var result = [];
Object.keys(sortedGroup).forEach((key) => {
    const group = sortedGroup[key];
    group.forEach((data, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
            data.countGroup = group.length;
        } else {
            data.countGroup = null;
        }
        result.push(data);
    });
});
```

Doing the above code, I can now get the result I want.
Here's a demo.

```js
let data = [
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'}
];
data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.BatchNumber === b.BatchNumber) {
        return a.GroupCode.localeCompare(b.GroupCode);
    }
    return a.BatchNumber - b.BatchNumber;
});
const sortedGroup = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
    const key = `${item.BatchNumber}-${item.GroupCode}`;
    if (!sortedGroup[key]) {
        sortedGroup[key] = [];
    }
    sortedGroup[key].push(item);
});
var result = [];
Object.keys(sortedGroup).forEach((key) => {
    const group = sortedGroup[key];
    group.forEach((data, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
            data.countGroup = group.length;
        } else {
            data.countGroup = null;
        }
        result.push(data);
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

Lastly, I will add the property named **countBatch** in the data. Since the value will count the Batch, I create a variable and a method that count the batch: Here's the method I used:

```
const batchCounts = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
    if (!batchCounts[item.BatchNumber]) {
        batchCounts[item.BatchNumber] = 0;
    }
    batchCounts[item.BatchNumber]++;
});
```

And then, add the result of `batchCounts` inside the iteration of `sortedGroup`. I add variable called `batchCount` with value of `batchCounts[group[0].BatchNumber]`. This shows the count value of BatchNunber and just pass it to iterattion of group by doing `data.countBatch = batchCount;`

**The PROBLEM is; the value of *countBatch* is inserted everytime the *countGroup* value is inserted. I want only to insert the value of *countBatch* in the first data of each batch number.**

**CURRENT**

```js
let data = [
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'}
];


data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.BatchNumber === b.BatchNumber) {
        return a.GroupCode.localeCompare(b.GroupCode);
    }
    return a.BatchNumber - b.BatchNumber;
});
const sortedGroup = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
    const key = `${item.BatchNumber}-${item.GroupCode}`;
    if (!sortedGroup[key]) {
        sortedGroup[key] = [];
    }
    sortedGroup[key].push(item);
});
const batchCounts = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
    if (!batchCounts[item.BatchNumber]) {
        batchCounts[item.BatchNumber] = 0;
    }
    batchCounts[item.BatchNumber]++;
});
var result = [];
Object.keys(sortedGroup).forEach((key) => {
    const group = sortedGroup[key];
    const batchCount = batchCounts[group[0].BatchNumber];
    group.forEach((data, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
            data.countBatch = batchCount;
            data.countGroup = group.length;
        } else {
            data.countBatch = null;
            data.countGroup = null;
        }
        result.push(data);
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

**EXPECTED**

```js
let expected = [
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A', countBatch: 6, countGroup: 3},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A', countBatch: null, countGroup: null},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A', countBatch: null, countGroup: null},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B', countBatch: null, countGroup: 2},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B', countBatch: null, countGroup: null},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'C', countBatch: null, countGroup: 1},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'A', countBatch: 4, countGroup: 1},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'B', countBatch: null, countGroup: 1},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C', countBatch: null, countGroup: 2},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C', countBatch: null, countGroup: null}
];
console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest modification you can probably make to your existing code is to `delete` the current batch number from your `batchCounts` object and then only add the `batchCount` if you get a number from your `batchCounts` object:

```js
let data = [
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'}
];


data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.BatchNumber === b.BatchNumber) {
        return a.GroupCode.localeCompare(b.GroupCode);
    }
    return a.BatchNumber - b.BatchNumber;
});
const sortedGroup = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
    const key = `${item.BatchNumber}-${item.GroupCode}`;
    if (!sortedGroup[key]) {
        sortedGroup[key] = [];
    }
    sortedGroup[key].push(item);
});
const batchCounts = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
    if (!batchCounts[item.BatchNumber]) {
        batchCounts[item.BatchNumber] = 0;
    }
    batchCounts[item.BatchNumber]++;
});
var result = [];
Object.keys(sortedGroup).forEach((key) => {
    const group = sortedGroup[key];
    group.forEach((data, index) => {
        const batchCount = batchCounts[group[0].BatchNumber];    
        if(batchCount != undefined) {
          delete batchCounts[group[0].BatchNumber];
          data.countBatch = batchCount;
        } else {
          data.countBatch = null;
        }
        
    
        if (index === 0) {
            data.countGroup = group.length;
        } else {
            data.countGroup = null;
        }
        result.push(data);
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

---

On a side note, I suggest you look at storing your keys in an ES6 Map so that when you iterate the keys, they come out in an expected order in all environments. You can also build `batchCounts` as you build `sortedGroup` object to avoid an additional iteration, eg:

```js
const sortedGroup = {};
const batchCounts = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
    const key = `${item.BatchNumber}-${item.GroupCode}`;
    batchCounts[item.BatchNumber] = (batchCounts[item.BatchNumber] || 0) + 1;
    if (!sortedGroup[key]) {
        sortedGroup[key] = [];
    }
    sortedGroup[key].push(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by adding temporary property in data object. Call that property inside the `group` iteration and set the value of **countBatch** and then, delete the temporary property. Thanks to @Nick Parsons that give me a hint. I still accept his answer.

```js
let data = [
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'}
];

data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.BatchNumber === b.BatchNumber) {
        return a.GroupCode.localeCompare(b.GroupCode);
    }
    return a.BatchNumber - b.BatchNumber;
});
const sortedGroup = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
    const key = `${item.BatchNumber}-${item.GroupCode}`;
    if (!sortedGroup[key]) {
        sortedGroup[key] = [];
    }
    sortedGroup[key].push(item);
});
const batchCounts = {};
data.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.tempBatchCount = batchCounts[item.BatchNumber] //added this line;
    if (!batchCounts[item.BatchNumber]) {
        batchCounts[item.BatchNumber] = 0;
    }
    batchCounts[item.BatchNumber]++;
});
var result = [];
Object.keys(sortedGroup).forEach((key) => {
    const group = sortedGroup[key];
    const batchCount = batchCounts[group[0].BatchNumber];
    group.forEach((data, index) => {
        data.countBatch = !(data.tempBatchCount) ? batchCount : null; //added this line;
        delete data.tempBatchCount; //added this line;
        if (index === 0) {
            data.countGroup = group.length;
        } else {
            data.countGroup = null;
        }
        result.push(data);
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the added info. This can be done using [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) when it is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_groupby).

```js
let data = [
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 1, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'B'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'A'},
    {BatchNumber: 2, GroupCode: 'C'}
];

data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.BatchNumber === b.BatchNumber) {
        return a.GroupCode.localeCompare(b.GroupCode);
    }
    return a.BatchNumber - b.BatchNumber;
});

// defines what attribute needs to be added based on keys
const attributes = {
  countGroup: ['BatchNumber', 'GroupCode'],
  countBatch: ['BatchNumber']
}

Object.entries(attributes).forEach(([key, identifiers]) => {
  Object.values(Object.groupBy(data, item => identifiers.map(id => item[id]).join())).forEach(group => {
    group.forEach((item, i) => item[key] = i ? null : group.length);
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This shorten my code :)